# Who is 本人 referring to in 本人には自覚は全くないんだがな

Tags: meaning

Person 1「ふむ……魅力的な提案だが、今はよしておこう。こちらも色々と仕事があるのでね」

Person 2「今は……ね。ああ、でも貴方に手を付けちゃうとガーネットに怒られそう。姫様にも色々言われそうだわ。　私よりもよっぽど面倒そうじゃない」

Person 1「**本人には自覚は全くないんだがな**――　まあ、その様子なら大丈夫だとは思うが、面倒事が起こる前に用事を済ませて帰れよ？」

I was under the impression that 本人 is third person, and if he was referring to ガーネット or 姫様 then he would have used 本人たち instead. In this case then I think it would refer to the person he is talking to, but I don't quite understand. Does anyone care to clarify who he is referring to?

Edit: Context:

Person 2 jokingly "invited" Person 1 to sleep with them.

1) Why would ガーネット get angry if Person 2 slept with Person 1?

Person 1 is an Incubus who in the past has deceived ガーネット and slept with her, she would naturally get angry if her friend sleeps with the same man she detests.

1) Why would 姫様 get angry if Person 2 slept with Person 1?

Person 1 is also technically her future husband.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the additional context provided I believe that 本人 refers to 姫様.

The statement 私よりもよっぽど面倒そうじゃない to me says that rather than "Person 1" or "Person 2" being more or less of a bother, it's referring to what they will have to face as a consequence if they sleep together(Person 2 would likely get an earful from ガーネット and Person 1 an earful from 姫様, and Person 2 thinks that dealing with 姫様 is going to be more troublesome than ガーネット)

Comment: Now that you point it out, this interpretation makes a lot of sense too.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, 本人 refers to a third person. But there are some cases where it refers to the speaker himself/herself in a third-person way.

- 「俺はよく面倒そうなやつだと言われるんだ。**本人**には自覚が全くないんだけどね」
  *People often call me a troublesome guy. But the person himself (= me) doesn't see himself that way at all.*
- 「**本人**は気にしてませんので、そんなに謝っていただかなくても結構です」
  *The person herself (= me) wasn't offended, so you don't have to apologize so profusely.*
- 「医者には自宅で休むようにと言われましたが、**本人**はいたって元気です」
  *The doctor told me to rest at home, but the person herself (= me) is feeling quite fine.*

I have no idea what your conversation is about, but you should consider the possibility that 本人 refers to Person 1 himself.

Comment: My problem if he was referring to himself objectively in third person would be linking the previous statement of 私よりもよっぽど面倒そうじゃない with what he said(本人には自覚は全くないんだがな) , as in context this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @roflcoptaz If he had said “全くないん**だな**”, I might interpret 本人 to be Person 2 (*“I guess you have no awareness that you are the more troublesome person”*). But since it is “全くないん**だがな**”, my guess is that it means “I really don't see myself as that troublesome, though”. Anyway, you know more about the story than I do, so in the end it's your call :)

Answer (score -2):

I think, 本人 refers to the person he is speaking to, since he said 「...私よりもよっぽど面倒そうじゃない」
Then, indicated by 「...**その**様子なら大丈夫だとは思うが...」 and imperatively asking him to clear things up and go home.「... 面倒事が起こる前に用事を済ませて**帰れ**よ？」